# How to change the date format from "Jan 21" to "01-21-2014" in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have date list. 
Jan21
Jan23

I want **Jan21** show as **01-21-2014** and **Feb5** show as **02-05-2014**. How do i do this in shell script?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
date -d 'Jan21' '+%d-%m-%Y'
```

Comment: Its not working for me...giving the error stating :-               date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]

Comment: Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: @sat Looks like it needs to be changed a little for bringing month value at beginning of date: date -d 'Jan21' '+%m-%d-%Y' - to work for linux

Comment: @user26228 Check this link if that helps : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fdate.htm - with options/eg